# Firebase Dynamic Links is not working for iOS in react-native

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links, react-native-firebase

I have setup Passwordless authentication for my react-native app, for that it required to setup firebase dynamic links which I did successfully.

And everything was working fine on both Platforms Android and iOS, but after I merged my branch with the master, it stopped working on iOS.
Meaning I am receiving the email to SignIn but that link is not opening the iOS app but it is working on Android successfully.

I did the following steps to setup Dynamic Links for iOS:

1. `AppDelegate.m`

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
@import Firebase;
//Deep Linking RNavigation Docs
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>
//Deep Linking RNavigation Docs

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
 RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
 RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                  moduleName:@"realyze"
                                           initialProperties:nil];

 rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

 self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
 UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
 rootViewController.view = rootView;
 self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
 [FIRApp configure];
 return YES;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
 return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
 return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}
//Deep Linking RNavigation Docs
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url
           options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
 return [RCTLinkingManager application:app openURL:url options:options];
}
//Deep Linking RNavigation Docs

@end
```

2. Added Association Domains Capability
   In Xcode and in my Apple Developer Account for the particular App
3. Added TeamID to Firebase Console for the appID prefix.
4. Added these Firebase Authorized Domains: 
   applinks:realyze.page.link
   activitycontinuation:realyze.page.link
5. Also added domains to an entitlements file

6.app-site-associations-file is also setup correctly

This setup worked for me before I merged my branch.

Help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: have you solved this issue already? fighting with the same problem! Is it opening in safari?

Comment: hey, any update?

Comment: @SafakCiplak @TobiasLins Yeah, turns out I was missing out on a few lines of code for handling ```Univeral Links``` in ```AppDelegate.m```, I have now deployed the app to Production.
I have answered with the code below

Comment: btw i found a that link hopefully someone helps
https://config9.com/apps/firebase/firebase-dynamic-link-not-opening-the-app-ios/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following lines of code to my `AppDelegate.m`:

```
//Universal Links

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler
{
 return [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                  continueUserActivity:userActivity
                    restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}
```

This worked for me and I have now deployed the app for Beta